# Can I limit Intellij Git Log to two or three branches?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, intellij-idea2017

I am trying to use Intellij's https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/log-tab.html

The Log tab is polluted by code changes from various different branches however the only branches I care about are the $MY_FEATURE_BRANCH and master (And perhaps one or two latest release branches)

In the branch filter of the log tab you can choose one specific branch or ALL branches. Is there anyway to only see the log of two (or a small number of) branches

Intellij 2017.1.5

Comment: In the branch filter i have a *Select* option which allows to select which branches to show, one per line

Comment: aaha. Of course! The word "Select" should perhaps be "Select multiple branches" or simply have checkboxes against every branch like excel filtering!

Anyways this works! I am happy to accept this as an answer if you post it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the branch filter of the log tab you can use the `Select` option which allows to select the branches you want to show.

You will have to insert branch names manually, one per line.